# Localstack, second ECS service fail to deploy

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, localstack

I'm deploying ECS service to localstack using terraform (tflocal). The first service is deployed without any issue and the task is running well. When I deploy a second service on the same cluster I get the following error:

Error: failed creating ECS service (default-ms_ops.com.envmng-svc): ServerException: An error occurred (ServerException) when calling the RunTask operation:
with aws_ecs_service.ecs_service, on main.tf line 89, in resource “aws_ecs_service” “ecs_service”:
89: resource “aws_ecs_service” “ecs_service” {

Looking at the localstack docker logs:

[ asgi_gw_5] localstack.request.aws : AWS ecs.CreateService => 400 (ServerException)

The second service is working well when deployed alone. I checked collision of name but the service is with a different name so its the only parameter that may cause a problem. All other parameters seems right (subnets, sg, taskdef,...).

Any clue what can be wrong?

I tried to deploy the second service as first and it worked fine. but then I deployed the first (as second) and it failed the same way.

Comment: Some of the features are not available in the free version, so check that first.

Comment: It's definitely in the Pro version: https://docs.localstack.cloud/aws/elastic-container-service/.

Comment: I have the pro version bought and payed for.

Comment: Then this is probably not the forum you want to ask that question in.

Comment: I'm asking this question in many places. I really need the answer.

Comment: I guess you bought the license so it's best to ask the support because this is not a terraform issue.